# How to evenly space dynamic checkboxes bootstrap and iCheck

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap and css. Using asp.net razor, I'm generating a dynamic set of checkboxes with bootstrap and the [iCheck](http://icheck.fronteed.com/) plugin. By hard coding the width in the CSS, I can get the appropriate spacing for a fixed set of input tags. However, this breaks once I resize the page. I then tried placing the checkboxes in a table, but it also doesn't work when resizing.

The css that was hardcoded for 8 `input` tags is:

```
.form-group label {
    display: inline-block; 
    min-width: 6em;
}
```

Based on my [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccakn5870/un9n3en9/6/), what I would like to achieve is in the **Form Group** section, even checkbox spacing, even page is resized.

My question is what is the proper way to evenly distribute the spacing of checkboxes, given a *dynamic* set of `input` tags, while resizing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the input and label in a new div called `wrap`

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="wrap">
    <input id="car1" class="checkbox-inline" type="checkbox" checked>
    <label for="car1" class="checkbox-label">Car</label>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <input id="car2" class="checkbox-inline" type="checkbox" checked>
    <label for="car2" class="checkbox-label">Sedan</label>
  </div>
...
</div>
```

Using flexbox, you can use `justify-content` and `flex-wrap` on `form-group` to distribute the new divs:

```
.form-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

You can give the div `wrap` a min-width too

```
.form-group .wrap {
  min-width: 8em;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/suax4p1L/4/)

Comment: Thanks this approach worked for me, I modified the display to `inline-flex`, justify-content to `flex-start` and min-width to use `px` instead if em. It now aligns properly even if resized.